# How to establish a remote connection with node potsgres?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, ssl

I am trying to create an API where I can query information from a database. The DB is hosted on my university's computer cluster. Here is the code I currently have

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'username',
  host: 'hostname-of-school-computer',
  database: 'db-name',
  password: 'pass',
  port: 5432
})

const getUsers = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM Inventory ORDER BY ingredient_id ASC', (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error.message
      }
      response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
  }
```

When I run this code and make a request on localhost, I get the error

```
no pg_hba.conf entry for host "165.xx.xx.172", user "username", database "db-name", SSL off
```

I tried adding `ssl: true` to the pool config but then got the error `self signed certificate in certificate chain`. Additionally, I have tried editing `pg_hba.conf` to listen to my school's host IP and that neither worked.

These are the lines I added to `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             165.xx.xx.172/0         md5
```

I am kind of a noob when it comes to JS and postgres so please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "self signed certificate in certificate chain"  This is the error you need to address.  Search for it, and you will find more questions (and answers) than you can shake a stick at.

Comment: Or maybe the real problem your editing of pg_hba.conf, if ssl is not the goal.  But since you didn't tell us how you edited it, and since "neither worked" isn't an error message, what can we tell you?

Comment: @jjanes I have updated my post to add what I added to pg_hba.conf. The error is saying that there is `no pg_hba.conf entry for host "165.xx.xx.172"` even though I literally manually added an entry for that exact host, so I am not sure what is going on with that. I will look at the SSL issue again, but I have already been down that path once.

Comment: If you restarted the server after changing pg_hba.conf, so that you know the change takes effect, then that should work.

Comment: Maybe port 5432 has been blocked by the firewall, So open the port in the firewall by using the command - ufw allow port-number/protocol.